# Blu-ray VlC problem

Tags: vlc, blu-ray

I got a problem with blu-ray player in VLC

Blu-ray error:
Blu-ray Disc is corrupted.
Your input can't be opened:
VLC is unable to open the MRL 'bluray:///dev/sr0'. Check the log for details.

It's not the discs

Answer (score 1):

The disc is probably a normal, commercial disc and thus encrypted.

Use

```
sudo apt-get install libaacs0 libbluray1 libbluray-bdj
```

and fetch the AACS keys with

```
mkdir ~/.config/aacs 
curl http://vlc-aacs.whoknowsmy.name/files/KEYDB.cfg > ~/.config/aacs/KEYDB.cfg
```

The AACS keys don't reach to 2013 and beyond, so if you want to watch something newer, you are out of luck.

You can install MakeMKV [from the ppa](https://launchpad.net/~heyarje/+archive/ubuntu/makemkv-beta) and use this to play newer stuff, if you don't mind having closed-source software with dubious status on your system.

For this, you need to remove the `libaacs0` again (`sudo apt remove libaacs0`) and make

```
cd /usr/lib
sudo ln -s libmmbd.so.0 libaacs.so.0
sudo ln -s libmmbd.so.0 libbdplus.so.0
```

after you installed MakeMKV to have VLC play and decrypt Blu-Ray discs.

To play a disc, you need to make some steps everytime to be successful:

Start MakeMKV, read the disc, press the "streaming" button in the top row.
Now start vlc, press `Ctrl`+`N` and paste `http://localhost:51000/stream/title0.ts` in the box. You might want to increase the buffer to 5000 ms or more under `More Options`.

You can see what titles are available on the disc in your browser under `http://localhost:51000`. If you substitute your IP address for 'localhost', you can even watch on other computers in your network as long as MakeMKV is active and streaming.

If you are on a relatively recent distro, you can safely substitute `apt` for `apt-get`. This is the future development and should be used if possible.

Comment: Blu-ray error:
Blu-ray Disc is corrupted.
Your input can't be opened:
VLC is unable to open the MRL 'bluray:///dev/sr0'. Check the log for details.

Still the same is it my driver?

Comment: So, what are the details from the log?

Comment: How do I check the log?

Comment: libbluray info: First play: 1, Top menu: 1 HDMV Titles: 12, BD-J Titles: 0, Other: 0
main error: open of `bluray:///dev/sr0' failed

Comment: @blendenzo: Originally, I omitted the link to MakeMKV because of its legal status. What's the policy of askubuntu regarding this?

Comment: I don't know. I mean I do have MakeMKV  install already. So could it just be something else?

Comment: Is it one disc, or all Bluray discs? Some discs can't be read by MakeMKV (yet).

Comment: All of  the blu ray  disc

Comment: Maybe you should do  a `sudo apt purge makemkv* vlc*` and reinstall MakeMKV and VLC. Without more hints, it's fumbling in the dark.

Comment: @emk2203:  as far as I know, askubuntu uses the general stackexchange content policy here: http://stackexchange.com/legal/content-policy  It doesn't say anything that would prevent posting that link.  I only added the link because my edit needed more characters, though.  I couldn't just add the "-get" to the end of "apt" like I wanted to.

Comment: It did not work. I reinstalled  it and the same thing. Sucks but at least I have DVDs and I just have to get a disc blu ray player

Comment: Is it just Linux?

Comment: What should I do?

Comment: I installed a new computer myself yesterday and could not make bluray work anymore on it. Maybe something has changed. For the moment, a hardware player or sequential use of MakeMKV to rip, then VLC or mpv to play is needed.

Comment: Thanks. I wonder if Linux will ever have a proper blu ray player

Comment: From the terminal, issue `makemkvcon stream:/dev/sr0`. Now do `vlc -f http://localhost:51000/stream/title01.ts`. You can also do a `Ctrl`+`N` in the GUI and use `http://localhost:51000/stream/title01.ts` as network address.

Does this work? If it does, I would like to put this as an answer.

Comment: When  I put it in the terminal it said Invalid command: stream:/dev/sr0and than when I used http://localhost:51000/stream/title01.ts it had your input could not be opened

Comment: Is your disc drive `/dev/sr0`?  This worked for me last week on a new installation of 16.04, so it is not theoretical. But you need to replace with the actual device name (could be `/dev/sr1` for example if you have two optical drives). Does MakeMKV work? What happens when you press the 'stream' button within MakeMKV? This is essentially what `makemkvcon` does, in the GUI.

Comment: Yes because the regular dvds can play it just fine in sr0. tried sr1 and it said the same thing. It seems like I can't stream it. So i guess I will have to just watch the dvds.

Comment: Maybe something like an update will come up soon

Comment: Is there anything else or that's it

Comment: Push the 'stream' button from within MakeMKV, open http://localhost:51000 in your browser afterwards. Do you see a webpage?

If this doesn't work, nothing else will. But it should.

Comment: https://youtu.be/xMABJHX2vPg?t=462

Comment: It worked.  Although the VLC will not play the disc menu it doesn't matter it plays. Thanks

Comment: @UsagiTsukino: If the answer is correct, please accept it to help others with the same problem. Makes it easier to find what works and what not. Thanks.